# How do I track changes in Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

In Microsoft Word, one can track changes.

How do I do so in Powerpoint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://www.microsofttraining.net/post-30554-powerpoint-compare-tracked-chang.html

You can make track changes in PPT 2010 but not in 2007.

Suppose you have 2 presentations PPT A and PPT B where changes have been made in PPT B.

1. Open PPT A and select Review tab, Compare.
2. Select and open PPT B.
3. The changes appear as Markup and a Reviewing pane appears on the right of the screen displaying PPT B as a slide or you can see the detailed changes.

You can also hover over the pencils to see what's changed. 
The Next and Previous buttons are like in Word where you can navigate to each change and accept or decline the change or accept/decline all changes.

In PPT 2007 you can only track inserted comments rather than compare any changes between 2 presentations.

This http://geigercomputers.com/track-changes-in-word-and-powerpoint/ also has similar answer but in more details.

Comment: The Compare feature isn't as powerful as Track Changes.  Word has both features; PowerPoint only has Compare.  The key differences: (1) Track Changes displays the changes inline instead of separately (2) Track Changes allows you to accumulate a whole stack of changes from multiple users.

Answer (score 5):

That depends somewhat on which version of PPT you have, but no version has anything like the tools Word does.

Basically, it boils down to users adding comments to a PPT file.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way is to do track changes manually - put a line through text you think should be deleted and make the font on added text red.  It's easier than screwing around with comment boxes and compare features.

If Dante wrote the Inferno today, he'd add another circle of Hell for Microsoft product developers.